# How to add image to button via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, resources, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to add image to buttons I have using Javascript but I can't seem to get it working. I have sucessfully added image using HTML5, however, for my needs I need to add the image via javascript.

Below is what I have written to add images via HTML.

```
<button class="button" id="Ok"><img src="images/ok.png"></button>
```

Below is what I have tried to add image via Javascript but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
      buttons[b].src = "images\ok.png";   
  }
```

I am not to sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, no luck. Getting this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need..

```
<button id="button"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttons = document.getElementById("button");
    buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images\ok.png" />';
</script>
```

Comment: I have 1 issue, because its a image inside the button, it overlaps the button and when I click the section of the button where the image is, the website doesn't seem to record my clicks.

Comment: is it possible to give the img tag the same id as the button it is in

Comment: please update your question above so that we can trace the problem. put your code above also....

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you're looking for.... this will set the buttons direct background as the image. But you must set the `width` and `height` options to your images width and height or it will be cut off or have white space, depending on the size of the button and image.

```
<style>
  button.button#ok
  {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
</style>
<button class="button" id="ok"></button>
<script>
  var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  for(var b=0;b<buttons.length;b++)
  {
    if(buttons[b].id=="ok")
    {
      buttons[b].style.background="url('images/ok.png')";   
    }
  }
</script>
```

## Edit, source

Here is the code in action:

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35742199/button.html

Here is the source of the code(which is above though):

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35742199/button.txt

And here is the image i used:

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35742199/cookies.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the button into a block element and give it a background image.

HTML:

```
<button class="button" id="Ok"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
display:inline-block;
background:none;
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
}
.button.okay{
background:url('images/ok.png');
}
```

JS:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
 buttons[b].classList.add("okay");
  }
```

Comment: Hi, tried this but its not working. Also, I want a way that only uses javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
buttons[b].firstChild.src= "images\ok.png";
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit Bhanderi, Rayon Dabre also suggested did but this provides me with an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing select tag , you only set src content for button element. Can you try with this

```
for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
   buttons[b].getElementsByTagName("img").src = "images\ok.png";   
}
```

Comment: Can you try to console.log how many <img> it can get inside looping.

for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
   buttons[b].getElementsByTagName("img").src = "images\ok.png";   
   console.log(buttons[b].getElementsByTagName("img"));
}
If it an empty array, we can try another way

Comment: What do you mean?, when I try console.log(b); it gives back 28 numbers this is because I have 28 buttons.

Comment: command "src" only apply for <img> tag. That why I'm try to get <img> tag inside <button>. May be some button do not have <img> tag, and looping will stop. On that case, you can put condition for that!

Comment: Oh, none of the buttons have img tag on them. I thought it won't be required because I wasn't adding image via html.

Comment: So, you need something like this;
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "images\ok.png");
buttons[b].appendChild(x);

Answer (score 1):

```
**TRY THIS**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
</head><body>
  <button class="button" id="Ok"></button>
<script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
      buttons[b].innerHTML = "<img src=\"ok/png\"/>";   
  }
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please Load Body Tag  First Then Load Your Script Tag.

Comment: Hi, this is initially adding the image through html <img src="images/ok.png"> because this buttons[b].firstChild.src = "images/ok1.png"; does not work.