# How to use images instead of text buttons in language-switch script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

i integrated this script into my website: `www.codepen.io/JFeremy/pen/QjpRaN?limit=all&page=2&q=language`

How can i use small images as buttons instead of the text buttons?
As soon as i change the text with an image,the translating function does not work anymore...

Can anybody tell me what i have to change to use small flags as buttons to change the language?

Thank you very much, Daniela

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image to button via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742199/how-to-add-image-to-button-via-javascript)

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery:**
You can use the $("#myClass") or $(".myId") selector to fetch the Jquery image object. Then apply the .click() method just like this:

```
let myObject = $(".myId");
myObject.click( () => {
    // handle the function here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but i have no clue where to integrate this code. can you help me. You finde the code of the script on the link i posted in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this ?

```
#fr_click {
background-image: url('https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/france/flag-400.png');
background-size: cover;
}
```

Just change the background of this button with img in Css ?

Comment: Thank you, but i wanted to get rid of the text for "Fr" and "En". But as soon as i remove it, the function doesnt work anymore. thx