# How to fix image source in jquery

Tags: jquery

I cannot find out why this image source is not working.
only last one is working fine(like 4 :text only).

Honestly speaking I'm not a jquery expert even don't have a bit idea about it and cannot find out what should I change.

```
if (reaction == 1) {
  $("#like1post" + post + "user" + user).attr("src", "helloone.png");
  $("#like2post" + post + "user" + user).attr("src", "hellotwo.png");
  $("#like3post" + post + "user" + user).text("<img src='hellothree.png'>");
  $("#like4post" + post + "user" + user).text("Like 4");
  $("#likeCountPost" + post).text(data);
```

```html
echo "<button id='like1post" . $post . "user" . $user . "' onclick='likeFunction(1, " . $post . ", " . $user . ")'>
<img src='logo/likedone.png' width='20'>
</button>";
```

Comment: Please click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML and images from placeholder.com to make a [mcve]

Comment: Seems if `$("#like3post" + post + "user" + user).text("Like 3");` works, then `$("#like3post" + post + "user" + user)` is not an image

Comment: @mplungjan its a part of a huge code.

Comment: We only want to see one example of the HTML that satisfies id="like3postxxxuseryyy"

Comment: You need to show the relevant HTML. Without that the question is incomplete and unsolvable. And then give the values for `post` and `user` as well.

Comment: echo "<button id='like1post" . $post . "user" . $user . "' onclick='likeFunction(1, " . $post . ", " . $user . ")'><img src='helloone.png' width='20'></button>";

Comment: Edit the question and add your example, don't add relevant code as a comment

Comment: Having said that, there's your issue:  `<button>` doesn't have a `src=` attribute to display an image, you need `<img src=` (as mentioned in the 2nd comment above)

Comment: there is <img src !!

Comment: `there is <img src !!` yes, but you're not selecting it. Add `img` to the end of the selector in the jQuery object.

Comment: add your full code.. we dont know how you are generating $post, or post in js code

Comment: are you trying to add image to button?

Comment: @AmanjotKaur yes

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742199/how-to-add-image-to-button-via-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$post=1;
$user=1;
echo "<button id='like1post" . $post . "user" . $user . "' onclick='likeFunction(1,".$post.",".$user.")'><img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRljWQ9H3Rtxh14io6tof4fDRgDnkU7JCQL9cLqhPGOFR3NEUGO' width='20'></button>";
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){   
     });
     function likeFunction(num,post,user)
     {
        $("#like1post" + post + "user" + user +" img").attr("src", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQdTEzB10rZPcdhjWzjv5TWs83Y7s-iRex6VefSy8pfRNwVV09e");
     }

</script>
```

I have just tried with only 1 button of yours... Try this. You are creating image in button.. so the image attr should be added to image only